# Can structural equation modeling be used with only categorical variables?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am interested in methods that will allow me to examine the relations between variables in a graphical manner. Structural Equation Modeling seems promising for my purposes. However, I only have categorical data and most of it is binary.

Is there a version of Structural Equation Modeling for ***exclusively*** categorical variables?

I know for Principle Component Analysis (PCA), Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA) is the analog for categorical data, so I'm looking for a similar analog for SEM that allows me to work exclusively with categorical data.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, it can. The only issue is that the association measures between covariables are based on the covariance, or equivalently the linear regression slope coefficient. The adaptation that SEM can make to accommodate one or more categorical variables is to use robust standard errors, or bootstrap. From a linear regression perspective, this is precisely the modification we would require so that the association measures (be they "weights" or "effects" or whatever the preferred terminology be) and their inference are consistent and interpretable.

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can see SEM for exclusively categorical variables? so far I've found mostly ones that involve either continuous or a mix of continuous and categorical, but none that are exclusively categorical.